# How to relate a column to the row rather than the other way in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have created a database in anylogic. Previously, I have related the information in the row to the columnn, i.e. there is a component in the row, and its properties are in the columns, and have put this in a function. Now I want to make the component the column and the properties, but don't know how to make it all relate. Below is the code I've written for the former:

`site = selectFrom(parameters) .where(parameters.box_number.eq(boxNumber)) .where(parameters.site.eq(site)) .firstResult(parameters.site);`

So box_number is the component and site is one of the properties. With this method, site is a column, but I want it to be a row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SELECT WHERE SQL syntax, see https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2Fquerying.html&resultof=%22%73%65%6c%65%63%74%22%20%22%77%68%65%72%65%22%20

You can filter and load data in any format. Also, best use the database query wizard to help:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the database query wizard to come up as its not highlighted

Comment: you must be in an active code field, i.e. have the cursor blink in a code field. Also, if the answer was helpful, please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)